# NoClassDefFoundError when starting tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have a project called EDIUtils  and a webservice that is using the EDIUtils jar.
Since I changed the build path in my eclipse from referring to the EDIUtils as a jar (I mean in the build path under liberties tab) to a Project  (under project tab ) 
my local tomcat is not starting and I keep getting the following message 
I tried to remove the tomcat , servers , clean project , restart eclipse 
Nothing helps – any ideas ?

By the way I don’t know if this means any thing but the Caused by message says

```
“Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ledi/nhia/com/EDIUtils;”
```

With the letter `L` before the real path  (`edi/nhia/com/EDIUtils`)

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/CPCBridge]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/CPCBridge]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ledi/nhia/com/EDIUtils;
```

the tomcat is local on my computer - i tried removing it and the server and adding it again - it did not work , i don't think this is related to the tomcat ,by the way when i created WAR file and deployed it on tomcat server ( not localhost ) it is working fine ,also when i close the project and reboot the tomcat - it is also botting so it look like some thing localy on my configuration

**UPDATE**

when i adding the EDIUtils.jar to WebContent/WEB-INF/lib (in the IDE ) the tomcat is rebooting - so actualy my question is 
**how the jars on the class path (compile time) are used by tomcat in runtime (since i understand runtime jars in tomcat are taken from the WebContent/WEB-INF/lib)**

Comment: What's your tomcat configuration ? Especially the deployment location: if your project is deployed in your eclipse metadata or in the tomcat real deployement folder (so you can check there of the jar exists). Also, do you use maven ? is it a Spring application ?

Comment: the tomcat is local on my computer - i tried removing it and the server and adding it again - it did not work

Comment: What have you configured in project's "deployment assembly" ?

Comment: yessssssssssssssss !!!!!!!!! thank you !!!!!!!!   i added the EDIUtils and now it  is working     project->properties->Deployment assembly ->add -> project - >chose my project